# make boolean false if any of boolean is false but i want to make it true when non of them is false

Tags: java, android, boolean

i need to know if all of array classes have variable move is true

```
  public boolean move,move2;


public ArrayList<DownBlocks> getBlocks() {
    return blocks;
}

public ArrayList<DownBlocks> getDones() {
    return dones;
}

 @Override
    public void render(float delta) {

  for (DownBlocks downBlocks:getBlocks()){
            if (!downBlocks.move){move=false;} }
```

this code works fine to make `move` false if any of `downblocks.moves` is false but i want to make it true when none of them is false

Comment: `false` iff any move is `false` is equivalent to `true` iff none are `false` - all are `true`. Simply set `move = true` before looping over the blocks and you’re done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
move = true;    
for (DownBlocks downBlocks:getBlocks()){
    move = (move && downBlocks.move)
    if (!move) {break};
}
```

Comment: i think that its a for loop so that the move will change in etch time the for loop will run so i will got only the last class in the array .move

Comment: Be more specific: is it only the getBlocks that you're interested in or are there any other lists that need to be checked.

Comment: no its just this arraylist but i have tried this code but i thing it copy the last value for the last class in the list hope you understand what i mean

Comment: It checks every member of the array until it finds the 1st false. if it finds false it stops because at least 1 is false and the variable move is false. if it does not find false then the variable move is true at the end. Why don't you try it?

Comment: See my edited code, I removed boolean from the 1st line

Answer (score 1):

Use this assigment:

```
move = downBlocks.move && downBlocks.move1 && downBlocks.move2;
```

`move` becomes true only when all `downBlocks.move???` are true, otherwise becomes false.

Comment: i think you didn't understand what i mean 
downblocks is a class in an array that have the variable  move and every class in the array have a different value for the move variable.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
move = downblocks.moves1 && downblocks.moves2 && ... && downblocks.movesN;
```